# Select element inside same div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 input type and two div with equal name.

```
<div>
<input class="palmetta" type="checkbox" name="palmetta[]" value="1"> Palmetta
<input class="palmettah" type="text" value="0" name="palmetta[]" ><br>
</div>

<div>
<input class="palmetta" type="checkbox" name="palmetta[]" value="1"> Palmetta
<input class="palmettah" type="text" value="0" name="palmetta[]" ><br>
</div>
```

There is a way to target only "palmettah" on the first `div` when I check the "palmetta" on the first `div`?

I have create this:

```
$("div .palmetta").change(function() {

if(this.checked) {
    $(".palmettah").prop('disabled', true);
} else {
    $(".palmettah").prop('disabled', false);
}

});
```

This script disable all `palmettah` but I need to disable only the `palmettah` inside the same `div` of the checked input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select input element based on the change event fired element for that use **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** method since it's immediately next to the checkbox. Although if condition is not necessary here instead use `this.checked` as the second argument in **[`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)** method.

```
$("div .palmetta").change(function() {
    // get the element `this` refers to it's dom object
    $(this)
       // get the element next to it
       .next()
       // update `disabled` property based on 
       // `checked` property of checkbox
       .prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

```js
$("div .palmetta").change(function() {
  $(this).next().prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="palmetta" type="checkbox" name="palmetta[]" value="1">Palmetta
  <input class="palmettah" type="text" value="0" name="palmetta[]">
  <br>
</div>

<div>
  <input class="palmetta" type="checkbox" name="palmetta[]" value="1">Palmetta
  <input class="palmettah" type="text" value="0" name="palmetta[]">
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can scope your query just to the current elements parent:

```
$("div .palmetta").change(function() {

  if(this.checked) {
    $(".palmettah",$(this).parent()).prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(".palmettah",$(this).parent()).prop('disabled', false);
  }

});
```

You can look upwards from the current element

```
....
$(this).parent().find('.palmettah').prop('disabled', false);
....
```

Or you can just look for siblings

```
....
$(this).siblings('.palmettah').prop('disabled', false);
....
```